# What is wrong with this C++ code? 3n+1 in programming-challenges/UVa

Tags: c++

The Programming-Challenges website marked it as a wrong answer. I checked with sample inputs and they were all correct. I added an optimization to the code, I made it so it doesn't check numbers that are known to be in another number's sequence, since it would be a subsequence and obviously have a shorter cycle length.

Also I just got back into programming so the program isn't too terse but I hope it is readable.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#inclue <vector>
struct record
{
   int number;
   int cyclelength;
};

void GetOutput(int BEGIN, int END)
{
    //determines the output order at the end of function
    bool reversed = false;
    if (BEGIN > END)
    {
        reversed = true;
        int temp = BEGIN;
        BEGIN = END;
        END = temp;
    }
    vector<record> records;
    for (int i = BEGIN; i <= END; ++i)
    {
        //record to be added to records
        record r;
        r.number = i;
        r.cyclelength = 1;
        records.push_back(r);
    }

    int maxCycleLength = 1;
    //Determine cycle length of each number, and get the maximum cycle length
    for (int i =0;i != records.size(); ++i)
    {
        //
        record curRecord = records[i];
        //ABCD: If a number is in another number's sequence, it has a lower cycle length and do not need to be calculated,
        //set its cyclelength to 0 to mark that it can be skipped
        if (curRecord.cyclelength != 0)
        {
            //
            while (curRecord.number != 1)
            {
                //next number in the sequence
                int nextNumber;
                //finds the next number
                if (curRecord.number % 2 == 0)
                    nextNumber = curRecord.number / 2;
                else
                {
                    nextNumber = curRecord.number * 3 + 1;
                    //if nextNumber is within bounds of input, mark that number as skippable; see ABCD
                    if (nextNumber <= END)
                    {
                        records[nextNumber - BEGIN].cyclelength = 0;
                    }
                }
                curRecord.number = nextNumber;
                curRecord.cyclelength += 1;
            }
            maxCycleLength = max(curRecord.cyclelength, maxCycleLength);
        }
    }
    if (reversed)
    {
        cout << END << " " << BEGIN << " " << maxCycleLength;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << BEGIN << " " << END << " " << maxCycleLength;
    }
}

int main(){
    //The first and last numbers
    vector< vector<int> > input;
    int begin, end;

    while (cin >> begin >> end)
    {
        //storage for line of input
        vector<int> i;
        i.push_back(begin);
        i.push_back(end);
        input.push_back(i);
    }


    for (int i = 0;i != input.size(); ++i)
    {
        GetOutput(input[i][0], input[i][1]);
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do?

Comment: You should try stepping through the code in gdb to see if its doing what you expected at the end of each iteration - ie, maintaining the loop invariant.

Comment: @Borealid: I'd guess he's deal with the [3n+1 problem](http://acm.uva.es/p/v1/100.html) on the UVa online Judge site;

Comment: Did it work before you added the optimization? It could be that you aren't dealing with a corner case like int overflow, or the case of n=1

Comment: Try a bigger gun. Erm, try a bigger input.

Comment: @user1434459: You sure your code can compile? It is missing namespace and `#include <vector>` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code apart from the typos mentioned above. This is very strange.

Comment: The code actually crashes with the largest input `1 1000000` (I run on Windows).

Comment: I submitted a much shorter program without the optimization and it's officially solved. The error is still a mystery but at least I can move on now.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give you a hint to nudge you into figuring out the problem.

The sample inputs are good as a smoke test, but they're often not good indicators that your program can handle the more extreme test cases too. You should always test with more than the sample inputs. If my calculations are correct, your program will produce the wrong result for the following input:

```
999000 999250
```

For reference, the expected output for this is:

```
999000 999250 321
```

There, I narrowed your search space down to 251 cycles :) Now get your debugger and finish the job.

Anyway, what follows is the full explanation and solution in spoiler markup. Mouse over the blank space if you want to read it, stay put if you want to figure it yourself.

> The problem states that i and j are less than one million and that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer. This means that no intermediate result will be larger than 4294967295. However, an `int` is a signed type, so, even if it has 32-bits, it only has 31 bits for the absolute value, and thus cannot fit any number larger than 2147483647. Numbers larger than these occur in the cycles of for several Ns in the problem range, one of which is 999167. Using an unsigned 32 bit integer is one solution.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. However, I don't know if the programming-challenges judge tests for cases where intermediate numbers exceeds the max number for the signed integer because I submitted my shorter solution without unsigned ints and it passed every test.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing mystery. The largest intermediate number overflows 31-bit of the signed integer. You need to declare `record.number` and `nextNumber` as `unsigned int`.